# Setting Magento Secure checkout Store view

Tags: magento

When you have three store views for a single store, each store view with it's own URL.
But a single HTTPS URL for the website.

How do you set the the `config/.htaccess` to maintain the store view in the secure checkout ?

Examples:

```
mysite.it
mysite.fr
mysite.de
```

All store views for language and locate specific sites checkout
via *mysite.eu*

Magento seems to only use the default store view?